# How to create a function to specify bin values in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to convert this Matlab code to Python.

```
x = [[12,  9,      6,  14,  8],
    [ 5,  19,     4,  25,  23],
    [ 4,  20,     5,  6,   19],
    [ 7,  2.30,   9,  28,  3],
    [16,  17,     5,  9,   27],
    [ 6,  9,      23, 5,   29]]

[NL_h,edgesL_h]= histcounts(x,'BinWidth',0.25);
```

Until now I've written the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

binwidth=0.25
(NL_h, edgesL_h, temp) = plt.hist(x.flatten(), bins=np.arange(min(x.flatten()), max(x.flatten()) + binwidth, binwidth))
```

The problem is with edge start. Python start with a minimum number `2.30` then `2.55` and so on. But Matlab starts from `2.25` and `2.50` and so on.
The values of `edgesL_h` and `NL_h` obtained are different from Matlab values.

So, is there any equivalence to this function in Python ?

**UPDATE**

You can see full details here:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array( [[12,  9,      6,  14,  8],
                [ 5,  19,     4,  25,  23],
                [ 4,  20,     5,  6,   19],
                [ 7,  2.30,   9,  28,  3],
                [16,  17,     5,  9,   27],
                [ 6,  9,      23, 5,   29]])
print(x)

binwidth=0.5
bins=[]
sum_=0

while sum_ <= np.max(x):
    bins.append(float("{0:.2f}".format(sum_)))
    sum_+=binwidth

if bins[-1] != np.max(x):
    bins.append(np.max(x))

print(bins)
print( np.min(x))

for index, item in enumerate(bins):
    if item > np.min(x):
        bins=bins[index-1 : ]
        break

N, edges= np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
print(edges)

  [  2.    2.5   3.    3.5   4.    4.5   5.    5.5   6.    6.5   7.    7.5
       8.    8.5   9.    9.5  10.   10.5  11.   11.5  12.   12.5  13.   13.5
      14.   14.5  15.   15.5  16.   16.5  17.   17.5  18.   18.5  19.   19.5
      20.   20.5  21.   21.5  22.   22.5  23.   23.5  24.   24.5  25.   25.5
      26.   26.5  27.   27.5  28.   28.5  29. ]

(NL_h, edgesL_h, temp) = plt.hist(x.flatten(), bins=np.arange(min(x.flatten()), max(x.flatten()) + binwidth, binwidth))

print(edgesL_h)

[  2.3   2.8   3.3   3.8   4.3   4.8   5.3   5.8   6.3   6.8   7.3   7.8
   8.3   8.8   9.3   9.8  10.3  10.8  11.3  11.8  12.3  12.8  13.3  13.8
  14.3  14.8  15.3  15.8  16.3  16.8  17.3  17.8  18.3  18.8  19.3  19.8
  20.3  20.8  21.3  21.8  22.3  22.8  23.3  23.8  24.3  24.8  25.3  25.8
  26.3  26.8  27.3  27.8  28.3  28.8  29.3]
```

Comment: the minimum value in `x` is 2, not 2.3

Comment: @DanielF yes that was my mistake. edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your `bins` to start from an even multiple, you'll probably have to define it as such.

```
def py_BinWidth(x, bw):
    start = np.floor(x.min() / bw) * bw
    end = np.ceil(x.max() / bw) * bw + bw
    return np.arange(start, end, bw)
```

then you can do

```
(NL_h, edgesL_h, temp) = plt.hist(x.flatten(), bins = py_BinWidth(x, binwidth))
```